# VS Code showing "type/arguments" in editor as labels

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just installed VS Code 1.60.0-insider.

At first I thought it was a bug, but now there are type/arguments hinds/labels in the editor:

[image]

(`predicate:`, `callbackfn:`, etc.)

How is this called and how to disable it? I searched online but couldn't find any information.

Note: they only appear in TypeScript files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try use this instruction inside of settings.json, this working well for me.

```
"editor.inlayHints.enabled": false
```