# Anyone know how to hide this keywords on VSCode ("create", "name" in this example)?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Yesterday I didn't have these words on my editor but today they showed up, I didn't change any configuration on the VSCode, anyone know how to hide them?

[image]

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/68841961/3001761?

Comment: That helped me, thanks!